# Use Pytesseract to Extract Text into Table Arrays Given the Coordinates of the Table Structure

Tags: opencv, ocr, tesseract, text-mining, python-tesseract

I want to extract texts from a scanned table with `tesseract` and put it them into arrays that have the same structure as the table.

I already used `opencv` to detect the table structure, and obtained the coordinates of the table joints as well as the entire table structure (stored into `np.array`).

For example, for the table in this picture:
[image]

I want `pytesseract` to store it into:

```
my_table = [[x, y, 1, 3],
            [x, a, 2, 3],
            [x, a, 2, 3],
            [x, z, 2, 3]]
```

I have used commercial OCR softwares and they always detect the table structure first, and secondly, recognize and extract texts to that detected table structure.

How do I accomplish the second step with pytesseract? Answers using Tesseract in other languages are great as well.